# Run Gradle Java Project in background

Tags: java, linux, gradle

I have built a Java project using Gradle. It is working fine. I have to run this project on Linux and I want to do it without the terminal window.

If I close the terminal, the project terminates.

How can I run the program without the terminal window?

Comment: What means "run project"?

Comment: yes to run project.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `nohup` command:

```
nohup <your_command_line> >Output.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: thank you. My gradle command is 'gradle runEngineWithMonitoring' , I tried nohub gradle runEngineWithMonitoring >Output.log 2>&1 & .command is not giving result. In Output.log 'nohub: command not found' is showing.

Comment: @maheshchouhan then the gradle command is not found. add the full path to gradle

Comment: gradle runEngineWithMonitoring is running. But it was not running in background.

Comment: @m it runs in the Background.

Comment: /usr/bin/nohup  gradle runEngineWithMonitoring  >Output.log 2>&1 &
 is working. Thank youJens

Comment: @maheshchouhan You are welcome. If it helps, feel free to upvote my answer

Answer (score 1):

I found answer to my question . My command is 'gradle runEngineWithMonitoring'.

I can now run this process in background, even after close of terminal in linux by following below steps.

Run

> gradle runEngineWithMonitoring &

command.
 after this run

> disown

command.